# Remove stuff through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So basically I want when I press on the Button I want to Icon to disappear as well as Button. I have tried something but clearly, it is not working, so I would appreciate some help if possible

```
const Button = (props) => {
  const[toggleIcon, setToggleIcon]=React.useState('true')
  function Icon() {
    toggleIcon(false)
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <button  onClick={()=> setToggleIcon('false')}></button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Button

const Icon = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Icon>{props.Icon('false')}</Icon>
    </div>

export default Icon
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent a component from rendering by returning `null`. Use conditional rendering with the `toggleIcon` state as the condition. The `onClick` handler changes the state.

E.G.:

```js
const Button = () => {
  const [toggleIcon, setToggleIcon] = React.useState(true)

  return toggleIcon ? (
    <button onClick={() => setToggleIcon(false)}><Icon /></button>
  ) : null
}

export default Button
```

Take a look at the [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) section of the React docs.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. I'm answering the user's question.

Comment: It was addressed to OP. He deleted the comment.